# Where to Host applications installer

Tags: discussion

Hi, Any one knows a place to host my app installer? any recommendation, I am creating my website and will put it there but before I have my site i need to put it some where so you guys can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend [box.net](http://box.net).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try somewhere like [drop.io](http://drop.io). Easy to use, and registration is optional. It's also much better than the horrible, crippled sites like MegaUpload or RapidShare.